# Can I import modules in python using a function

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-module

I am working on a small library and I need to know can I import modules like numpy, sklearn and etc. Using functions. For example:

```
def ml():
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
x = np.array([1,2,647,345,3,7,3,8,36,64])
```

Is this possible ?
Simply can I import a module using a function and then use that later outside the function
The main idea is when the user calls the function ml he has all the modules related to machine learning imported and then he can use them. X = np.array was just kind of an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATED***

This should work

```py
import importlib
def importmd(modulex):
    return importlib.import_module(modulex) #Returning the module
np = importmd("numpy") #Same as import numpy as np
```

Comment: Hi. What's the difference with just using `import numpy` in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: MasayoMusic just an example

Comment: Not Working GameDev

Comment: This is a working code, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: after pasting your code i typed `x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,4,3,2,])`
I got numpy not defined

Comment: That means numpy isn't installed in your system and if it's make sure you've typed  `numpy` in double inverted commas i.e `"numpy"`

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer, my bad :(